# Working code for giving android 6.0 app permission to write to internal storage with appcelerator

Tags: android, permissions, titanium, appcelerator

Im trying to solve this for three days, tried many different codes I could find with zero results. Anyone knows how to give android app running in `android 6.0` device `permission` to write to internal storage with `appcelerator`? SDK 5.4.0 or 5.3.1

Comment: After long searching and reading, i cannot even find that apps need permission to write to internal storage, so I have noidea why my app has default settings with storage permission denied.

Comment: Have you tried http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Filesystem-method-requestStoragePermissions and http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Filesystem-method-hasStoragePermissions???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok with help from guys from appcelerator, it seems i have finally working code example.

in index.js

```
function doClick(e) {
if (!Ti.Filesystem.hasStoragePermissions()) {
Ti.Filesystem.requestStoragePermissions(function(result) {
  console.log('Permission granted? ' + result.success);
  if (result.success) {
    getFile();
  }
  else {
    alert('Permission denied.');
  }
});
  }
else {
getFile();
}
}
function getFile() {
  var url = "http://www.appcelerator.com/wp-content/uploads/GettingStartedTitanium_Linux.pdf";
var fileName = "GettingStartedTitanium_Linux.pdf";

var httpClient = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient();
httpClient.onerror = function(e) {
alert('Download Error: ' + e.error);
};
httpClient.onload = function(e) {
var filePath = Ti.Filesystem.tempDirectory + Ti.Filesystem.separator + fileName;
var f = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(filePath);
var file = f.write(this.responseData);
alert('File exist? ' + f.exists());
};
httpClient.open('GET', url);
httpClient.send();
}
$.index.open();
```

In "index.xml"

```
<Alloy>
<Window class="container">
<Label id="label" onClick="doClick">Hello, World</Label>
</Window>
</Alloy>
```

In "Tiapp.xml" Android section

```
<android xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<manifest>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="23"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
</manifest>
</android>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this module, that is actually a workaround:
https://github.com/gimdongwoo/Ti-Android-RequestStoragePermission